# Linux: Set permissions to Windows network computers

Tags: windows, linux, permissions

Im working on a linux server at work and I wanted to find out how to set certain permissions to Windows users connected to that server.

Im trying to assign permissions to windows machines connected to the linux server?

This is how the network is setup... There are different computers that are connected in a network, that connects to a dedicated lunix (debian) server. On the server there is a shared folder that all of the computers can access.

What I would like to do is set a read & execute permission to a certain computers in that Windows network. Is there a way to set certain permission to a specific computer by its Computer Name (Full computer name, ex. Garys-pc) and Workgroup Name through the linux system to set certain permissions?

How can I do this? Im a novice with the linux operating system so I would appreciate any help with this. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `smb.conf(5)` man page, **VARIABLE SUBSTITUTIONS** section, details all variables that can be used in the configuration file. These variables can be used in an `include` directive in order to include other files that can modify global behavior.

Comment: I took a look at the variables in the man page, but not sure how to apply them. Within the linux server, in the "Network" section, I can see all the windows machines that are connected to the server. There is a particular machine/computer within that network that I want to limit permissions to so that they can only read and execute. I don't want them to be able to modify, move, or delete anything. How would I do this?